# Android: EditText Text size to grow according to content? Possible

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am stuck here. If my input is a "**small string**" it should be bigger in font to occupy more screen area of the EditText field area and if the input is "**this is a large sting input**" it should resize and fit into the EditText box view accordingly. Any suggestions.....?

Comment: you can add `onTextChangeListener()` on `EditText` and then change font size `onTextChanged` callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you will have to apply a check in your ontextchanged implementation and after a certain threshold say 30 characters, you can decrease its fontsize at runtime in the code.